# How do I provide filter parameters on Undertow/EAP 7?

Tags: java, jboss, undertow

I've written a custom filter for Undertow/EAP7, and have dropped it in the server config file.  My XML looks something like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            .
            .
            <filter-ref name="myFilter" />
        </host>
    </server>
    .
    .
    <filters>
        .
        .
        <filter name="myFilter" module="josh.example.myFilter" class-name="josh.example.myFilter">
        </filter>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

How do I:

1. Provide parameters to this filter in the XML configuration
2. Consume those parameters in Java code

I've searched the docs a bit, and the [undertow handler author's guide](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html#undertow-handler-authors-guide) is silent on the matter, as well as the [JBoss EAP 7 web server config guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0.beta/configuration-guide/chapter-9-configuring-the-web-server-undertow).

**Update:**
Just found [the .xsd](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/undertow/src/main/resources/schema/wildfly-undertow_3_0.xsd), parameters can be added to the XML like this:

```
<filter name="myFilter" module="josh.example.myFilter" class-name="josh.example.myFilter">
    <param name="foo" value="bar" />
</filter>
```

However, still looking to see how I can consume these on the Java handler side.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I figured out a solution after perusing the source + a bit of trial and error.  Here's what worked for me:

Per the [widlfly-undertow_3_0.xsd](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/undertow/src/main/resources/schema/wildfly-undertow_3_0.xsd) spec (current at time of writing), you can add an arbitrary number of parameters like this:

```
<filter name="MyFilter" module="josh.example.MyFilter" class-name="josh.example.MyFilter">
    <param name="foo" value="bar" />
    <param name="magicNumber" value="7" />
</filter>
```

Then, create some bean-like setters matching the parameter names on your filter:

```
public class MyFilter implements HttpHandler {
   public void setFoo(String foo) {
      log.info("set foo to {}", foo);
   }

   public void setMagicNumber(Integer magicNumber) {
      log.info("set magicNumber to {}", magicNumber);
   }
}
```

I also attempted to use the fields as constructor parameters like so:

```
public class MyFilter implements HttpHandler {

   public MyFilter(HttpHandler next, String foo, Integer magicNumber) {
   // do stuff
   }
}
```

However, when configured in the JBoss server configuration file (typically something like *standalone.xml*), the [ConfiguredHandlerWrapper](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/undertow/src/main/java/org/wildfly/extension/undertow/deployment/ConfiguredHandlerWrapper.java) always grabs the `HttpHandler` constructor and ignores the rest.  As such, this approach will not work on EAP7.